# How to extract Data Which got from Client on server?

Tags: vb6

I am working on vb6 and create server project using winshock component successfully. Client (Biochemistry Analyzer software) is connected and send data to server after test perform. it comes in the form of string i.e

```
MSH|^~\&|Factory|Chemistry Analyzer|||20210430190330||ORU^R01|9|P|2.3.1||||0||ASCII|||
PID|9||||shitalPL||||||||||||||||||||||||||
OBR|1||11|Factory^Chemistry Analyzer|N||20210430183639||||||||Serum|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
OBX|1|NM|GLU|GLU|198.452857|mg/dL|-|Normal|||F||198.452857|20210430183639||||
```

How I get the required values from this stuff. And store them in table for further use

For example, in this stuff:

1. Sample ID is `9`
2. Patient Name is `shitalPL`
3. sample type is `Serum`
4. test name is `GLU`
5. test result is  `198.452857`

Comment: It looks like your data is pipe-delimited with some values being null.  If this is the case, I would use the `Split` function to pull all the data into an array.  Then you can reference the array to get the values you need as you update the DB.

Comment: Thanks. Split function  works. thanks once again. Now I am able to seperate values that i required.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the values have fixed position in responses you can implement a function where you pass the `n` as a parameter and your function returns the position of nth pipe and then you can repeat this for `n+1` and then simply extract the data between the positions of `n` and `n+1` th pipe.

I can give you a sample code in python which i hope you can convert to vb6. The function would look something like this -

```
def findNthOccur(string, ch, N):
    occur = 0

    # Loop to find the Nth
    # occurence of the character
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if (string[i] == ch):
            occur += 1

        if (occur == N):
            return i

    return -1
```

This function will take the string in which you want to find the occurance, the character which u want to find ('|' in your case ) and `n` will be the nth occurance you want to find

Comment: Thank u very much. I got your point. I will try it in vb6 and revert about it.